# How to change the language for man command?

Tags: shell, man, settings

I wanted to ask if it was possible to translate the man and man explanations from the terminal (in Italian language). If, for example, use:

```
man cd
```

Instead of running in English I would that will print in Italian.

Comment: Which distribution are you using?  Do any of the suggestions on http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43384/ work for you?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can run it from your terminal:

```
man --locale=it
```

Comment: Note that this is equivalent to `man -Lit ` *`name`*, as identified in [Localization of man pages on Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/43384/23408#43498); see [man (1)](http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/1/man).

Answer (score 3):

First off, you have to have the man pages written in the language of your choice, obviously Italian for you. Then you check if the Italian language is in your locale. Run `locale -a` and see if you see something similar to `it_CH.iso88591` or `it_CH.utf8`. If you do, you are good so far, if not, edit `/etc/locale.gen` and uncomment the language sets you want. Then, as `root` user, run the command `locale-gen`.

```
LANG=it_CH.utf8 man command_name_here
```

again you must see the `it_CH.utf8` on the output of `locale -a` and you have to have man page written in Italian for the command you want to see the man page for.